# Trying to plot the fft of a sinc function

Tags: matlab, fft

I am trying to plot the fft of a set of data I have. These data form a nearly perfect sinc function. Here is the data of which I am trying to plot the fft:
[image: Here is the data of which I am trying to plot the fft].

I know the fft of a sinc function should look like kind of a step function. However, the results I get are nowhere near that. Finding the fft in itself is super easy, but I think my mistake is when I try to compute the frequency axis. I have found several methods online, but so far I have not been able to make it work. Here is my code:

```
sampleRate = (max(xdata) - min(xdata))/length(xdata);
sampleN = length(xdata);
y = fft(ydata, sampleN);
Y = y.*conj(y)/sampleN;
freq = (0:1:length(Y)-1)*sampleRate/sampleNumber;
plot(freq, Y)
```

I have found pretty much all of that online and I understand pretty much none of it (which might be why it's not working...)

Zoom on what I get using that code:
[image: Zoom on what I get using that code]

It now seems to be working! This is what I get when I subtract the mean:
[image: This is what I get when I subtract the mean]

Comment: Well, for one, you're plotting the power spectrum, not the FFT. Also, please include in your question what you are actually seeing. A screen shot of the plot would be useful. We don't have your data, so cannot reproduce what you see.

Comment: Thank you for specifying! I will read a bit about power spectrum, I guess! I have edited to include the plot I get using this code.

Comment: Try setting the 'XLim' property of the axes to `[0,0.0002]` or something like that, to zoom in on the beginning of the plot. Also, try setting the 'YScale' property to 'log'.

Comment: Using the 'Xlim' makes it kind of clear that the problem isn't what I thought: the Y doesn't look like a step at all. I updated the picture of what I get when I run the code.

Comment: @LudovicG when an answer is correct always hit its checkmark so other people can see its a good answer ... also in doing this you the OP also get rewarded with a few reputation points ;-) ... welcome to SO

Comment: @ScottStensland Oh thank you, I will! haha if you couldn't tell already, I'm pretty new at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see here is the zero frequency being much, much larger than everything else. Plot with `plot(freq,Y,'o-')` to prove that the shape you see is just the linear interpolation between two samples.

The zero frequency is the sum of all samples. Because the mean of your signal is quite a bit larger than the amplitude, the zero frequency dwarfs everything else. And because you are plotting the power (absolute square of the DFT), this difference is enhanced even more.

There are two simple solutions:

1. Plot using logarithmic y-axis:

   ```
   plot(freq, Y)
   set(gca,'yscale','log')
   ```
2. Subtract the mean from your signal, remove the zero frequency, or scale the y-axis (these are all more or less equivalent):

   ```
   y = fft(ydata-mean(ydata), sampleN);
   ```

   or

   ```
   y(1) = 0;
   ```

   or

   ```
   plot(freq, Y)
   set(gca,'ylim',[0,max(Y(2:end))]);
   ```